# What are \notes{} for in beamer?

Tags: beamer, texmaker, notes

I cannot put a lot of text in `\notes{}` so I wonder what it is used for.

I mean I would like to add comprehensive explanations to frames. But if I write too much text, a segmentation fault occurs.

I use Texmaker 3.5 to typeset the presentation and the language of notes is Russian.

Is it a limitation of beamer or a bug of Texmaker? How to assemble more compact notes in beamer?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show only notes}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Оценка воздействия на окрущающую среду лесозаготовительной и лесохозяйственной деятельности
\begin{block}{Уровни}
\begin{itemize}
\item Ландшафтный
\note {\textbf{Цель и объект сохранения на ладншафтном уровне}: 
Сохранение крупномасштабной динамики экосистем, планетарных функций лесов; крупные малонарушенные массивы}
\item Сообществ
\item Локальный
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\note {Оценка воздействия на окружающую среду (ОВОС) - выявление, анализ и учет прямых, косвенных и иных последствий воздействия на окружающую среду планируемой хозяйственной и иной деятельности в целях принятия решения о возможности или невозможности ее осуществления. ОВОС способствует принятию экологически и социально ориентированного управленческого решения о реализации намечаемой хозяйственной и иной деятельности посредством определения возможных неблагоприятных воздействий, оценки экологических последствий, учета общественного мнения, разработки мер по уменьшению и предотвращению воздействий.}
\note {ОВОС должна учитываться при разработке системы лесного хозяйства и лесопользования, подготовке плана лесоуправления (проекта освоения лесов) и другой проектной документации. Оценка включает в себя исследования на уровне ландшафта и определение воздействия на окружающую среду лесозаготовительной и дорожной техники и оборудования. ОВОС должна проводиться перед началом любых мероприятий, которые могут привести к нарушению природной среды.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I updated Texmaker to 3.5.1 and the segmentation fault disappeared. As you can see my notes for a frame cannot accomodate one page. My question is still the same: What is the purpose of the `\notes{}`? **What is a fair use of this command? How much text can I put in a note?**

Comment: We will need to see an example of you input: segmentation faults should not happen at all with TeX, so this seems very odd.

Comment: I updated Texmaker to recent version and no errors occur now. But my question still remains the same.

Comment: A note is text that is intended as a reminder to yourself of what you should say or should keep in mind when
presenting a slide. Notes are usually printed out on paper, but with two-screen support they can also be shown
on your laptop screen while the main presentation is shown on the projector[Ref:Beamer User Guide for version 3.22.].here is a nice one http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10197/15717

Comment: The whole of section 19 of the manual ('Adding Notes for Yourself') is about the notes system: could you elaborate on what is not clear from that?

Comment: I want to make comprehensive notes for myself. If execute the above mentioned code, my notes don't fit into the frame. How to put more notes?

Answer (score 3):

Citing [Beamer User guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) page 199 version 3.27

> A note is text that is intended as a reminder to yourself of what you should say or should keep in mind when presenting a slide. Notes are usually printed out on paper, but with two-screen support they can also be shown on your laptop screen while the main presentation is shown on the projector [Ref:Beamer User Guide for version 3.27.].

As suggested by  Joseph Wright

The whole of section 19 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) ('Adding Notes for Yourself' Ver 3.27) is about the notes system.

Here is a nice Q&A at TeX.SX [In beamer slide, view notes on computer only while presenting with a projector?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10197/15717)