# Speaker notes or powerpoint with beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations, slideshow

I'm making a presentation with `beamer`. I see in other publications that I can use `\note` to put speaker notes, but the slides appear side by side in the same screen, and don't split for both screens.

I search a bit about the subject but I can't find a viewer to solve this in Windows and Ubuntu.

1. How can I put this like power point, in a primary and second screen?
2. If there is no way, I can convert the beamer presentation to
   powerpoint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/is-there-a-specialized-pdf-viewer-for-latex-beamer-presentations-on-linux or http://dspdfviewer.danny-edel.de/

Comment: or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/is-there-a-nice-solution-to-get-a-presenter-mode-for-latex-presentations, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10197/in-beamer-slide-view-notes-on-computer-only-while-presenting-with-a-projector