# Beamer presentation with notes

Tags: beamer, notes

I would like to have some notes for my presentation so that I would be the only one to see them on my computer. So I used the show notes option of beamer. 

 
However, I need a software to read the presentation. As I'm on OS X,I tried splitshow but it seems they have some issues with their last release it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I could manage to do what I want ? (Another soft ? Another way ?)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56229/36296

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247939/36296

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214658/36296

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for these links. To share my own experience, the simplest and most functional solution for an OS X user, according to me, is Skim reader. 

It allows you to synchronize your notes with your presentation and works quiet well.